# How to explain heap and stack do not grow towards each other

Tags: .net, heap-memory, stack-memory

When I debug these lines of code, I can observe ms/ms2 are instances of value type and they are allocated on stack, and o (boxed MyStruct instance) is reference type and is allocated in managed heap.

I can view the addresses of ms and ms2 from a Watch window in Visual Studio, they are 0x0024f104 and 0x0024f0f0, respectively. So the stack is growing DOWN towards the bottom of the address space. Since stack and heap grow towards each other, the address region for the managed heap should be below 0x0024f0f0. But the address of o is actually 0x01e9312c, which means the heap does not grow towards the stack (although I can observe when new objects are allocated in the heap, their addresses are indeed growing UP).

Can someone help to explain this?

```
MyStruct ms = new MyStruct(1, 2, 4, 8); //0x0024f104, 16 bytes for ms
Object o = ms;                          //0x0024f100, 4 bytes for variable o
MyStruct ms2 = (MyStruct)o;             //0x0024f0f0, 16 bytes for ms2
```

Comment: I find this "Address space layout randomization is enabled by default starting from Vista" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows). So yes I now admit "stack and heap grow towards each other" is no longer valid.

Comment: No. This is not a reason. This is just one of memory management aspects. Stacks and other portions of memory within a process'es virtual address space are *allocated* at positions that are just available and not because of some need to 'grow'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack and head growing towards each other was a concept valid some 30 years ago.

Generally you don't have to and should not care of where in memory an object is located.

Comment: Unless you are trying to implement an attack ;)

Comment: Or design something like sql server, but in that case you wouldn't ask such questions at the first place :-)

Comment: It is still a valid concept in my opinion, how a process's virtual address space is partitioned is something that haven't been changed in modern Operating Systems. I doubt in this case, it is the Common Language Runtime (CLR) that do some extra work so the heap(s) can be anywhere in the address space, after all, it is called "managed heap".

Comment: @lc2817, I need to know the address of the objects because i want to do address-level debugging, visualized debuging is sometimes not sufficient and I want to know how the value of each byte (of my insterested objects, of course) is changed.

Comment: @kennyzx can't you use a debugger?

Comment: @kennyzx You really do need to read something about modern memory management, multithready, and other operating system concepts that have impact of memory layout. Your assumptions are plain false. Start, for example, from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management.